# Should I combine these queries, and if so, how?

Tags: sql, query-optimization

I have 4 tables: Foo, Bar, Charlie, & Delta. Tables Charlie, Delta, & Bar all have a foreign key column containing the primary key for a Foo. The foreign key columns have the unique constraint, so no more than 1 of each can be linked to a given Foo. Furthermore, due to how the domain was modeled, there should never be both a Charlie and a Delta linked to the same Foo.

I have a Bar, and I would like to know if there is a Charlie or a Delta linked to the associated Foo, and if not then I need some other data from the associated Foo.

Currently I'm doing this as 1-3 queries:

1. Get the primary key for the Charlie linked to the Foo linked to the Bar, if there is one
2. If there isn't a Charlie, get the primary key for the Delta linked to the Foo linked to the Bar, if there is one
3. If there isn't a Delta, get some other columns from the Foo linked to the Bar

For historical reasons, we don't use stored procedures; each query is built in the code (we're using C#, if that's relevant for some reason) and its results are checked there before potentially running the next query.

For Oracle & for MS SQL Server 2008 (we support both), is it faster to run these 3 queries separately or to combine them into a single query somehow? If it's faster to combine them, how would I do so?

Edit: Think of each table as having two columns. Foo has columns PRIMARY_KEY and OTHER_DATA, while the other three tables have columns PRIMARY_KEY and FOO, where FOO is a foreign key containing the primary key for a row in Foo.

The 3 queries basically look like this:

1. `SELECT C.PRIMARY_KEY FROM Bar B, Charlie C WHERE B.FOO = C.FOO` (returns 0 or 1 rows)
2. `SELECT D.PRIMARY_KEY FROM Bar B, Delta D WHERE B.FOO = D.FOO` (returns 0 or 1 rows)
3. `SELECT F.OTHER_DATA FROM Bar B, Foo F WHERE B.FOO = F.PRIMARY_KEY` (returns 1 row)

Comment: Any chance we could see some SQL?

Comment: a combination of `Foo inner join Bar`, a couple of `left join A` and `left join B` and a `where` that uses the left joins might work.

Comment: For starters you could fix your join syntax. I'm not sure where people are still being taught this but replace `FROM Bar B, Charlie C WHERE B.FOO = C.FOO` with `FROM Bar B INNER JOIN Charlie C ON B.FOO = C.FOO`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it could *potentially* be faster to combine them.
This is because you have a chance to avoid going back to Bar multiple times.

The long answer, of course, is that it always depends on your indexing and hardware setup (and everything else :) ).
So it is essential that you actually test the old way against any new way and look for a significant improvement.

Since you say all of these are 1-1 (or 0-1) relationships, what I'm seeing is that you are really making one, extended record for each Foo record.

There is nothing stopping you from writing

```
select
    foo.*       -- of course, specific columns is better
    ,bar.*      -- of course, specific columns is better
    ,c.*        -- of course, specific columns is better
    ,d.*        -- of course, specific columns is better

from
    foo
        inner join bar on foo.pk = bar.fooId
            left join charlie c on bar.fooId = c.fooId
            left join delta d on bar.fooId = c.fooId
```

I know SQL Server is capable of reaching out to Bar only one time in this case, saving processing and potentially disk I/O.
And because you are using the same join key for everything, that makes me even more confident because there is no issue of re-sorting the data for the different joins.
The database "engine" should be able to pipe them into each other very well.

Multiple queries should be a performance mistake because Bar is read again and again.

It's very likely the same argument applies to Oracle in such a basic operation, but I'm not an expert there.

Comment: `where c.fooId is null and d.fooId is null`

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Mike M.  Each round-trip to a database will slow-down your app and DB, significantly.
Having said that, you could make just one round-trip to your DB, although the result set might get kinda big, when you string together the results of 3 tables (just sayin).
This will work as long as tables Charlie, Delta and Foo are symmetrical (have the same columns) you could use a UNION statement to combine the results.  Like this

```
SELECT 'Charlie' AS SourceTable, C.PRIMARY_KEY 
FROM Bar B INNER JOIN Charlie C ON B.FOO = C.FOO
UNION
SELECT 'Delta' AS SourceTable, D.PRIMARY_KEY 
FROM Bar B INNER JOIN Delta D ON B.FOO = D.FOO
UNION
SELECT 'Foo' AS SourceTable, F.OTHER_DATA 
FROM Bar B INNER JOIN Foo F ON B.FOO = F.PRIMARY_KEY
```

Otherwise, Mike M's answer (using LEFT JOINs) would be a really good option too, as long as you don't have repeating .foo IDs in the other 3 tables (which would create cartesian products = evil).  You could avoid those by adding more WHERE clauses to Mike M's answer to filter out rows from other tables.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're coding in C#, you can use Linq to SQL:

```
var query = from f in Foo
            // inner equijoin:
            join b in Bar on f.PRIMARY_KEY equals b.FOO
            // left outer join:
            join tc in Charlie on f.PRIMARY_KEY equals tc.FOO into gc
            from c in gc.DefaultIfEmpty()
            // left outer join:
            join td in Delta on f.PRIMARY_KEY equals td.FOO into gd
            from d in gd.DefaultIfEmpty()
            // anonymous object for result set:
            select new {
                Key = f.PRIMARY_KEY,
                Data = f.OTHER_DATA,
                HasCharlie = c == null,
                HasDelta = d == null
            };

                      // get first row with charlie or delta
var resultRow = query.FirstOrDefault(row => row.HasCharlie || row.HasDelta);

if (resultRow == null)
{
                               // get first row, regardless of charlie or delta
    var otherResultRow = query.FirstOrDefault();
}
```

Building `query` could also be accomplished with a chain of method calls: `Foo.Join(Bar,...).GroupJoin(Charlie,...).SelectMany(...)` etc.

If you want to "bake in" the query results, you can assign `query.ToList()` to a variable, and perform future actions on that variable without hitting the database again, using Linq to Objects. Alternatively, if your future actions (such as `FirstOrDefault` in my above code) are being used on `query`, they'll reflect any changes to the database which occur during the execution of your code.